# Ingresar datos en consola de SublimeText3 para Java

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Estoy trabajando con Sublime Text 3 para compilar java, sin embargo cuando creo clases que necesiten el ingreso de datos por teclado, la consola de sublime text solo deja escribir pero cuando aprieto la tecla ENTER, no sucede nada, es como si el programa no leyera nunca el retorno o salto de linea, de manera que nunca sabe donde termina la cadena de texto.

Esta es mi configuracion de BuildSystem de Java

```js
    {
"cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
"file_regex": "^(...?):([0-9]):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",
"shell": true
}
```

El programa compila correctamente, pero no reconoce el final de la cadena de texto al ingresarlo en el shell de ST3, como puedo solucionar esto?

Este es el codigo que estoy tratando de compilar

```js
import java.io.*;
 class saludar{

  public static void main (String [] args){
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String nombre = "";
    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    try{
      nombre = inp.readLine();
      System.out.println("Hola " + nombre);
    }catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
  }

}
```

Como mencionaba, solo recibe todo lo que escriba por el teclado, pero la tecla ENTER solo agrega un salto de linea, en vez de la finalizacion del ingreso de datos

Comment: Te da algun error al ejecutar en consola?

Comment: Nada, simplemente ingresa caracteres infinitamente, hasta que le doy esc y sale de la consola...

Comment: Cuando digo "ingresa caracteres infinitamente" me refiero a que ingresa todo lo que escriba en el teclado, y con el ENTER solo hace un salto de linea pero sigue ingresando lo que escriba por el teclado

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de java para ver que hace tambien

Comment: Editando la pregunta puedes agregarlo

Comment: Ya lo agregue..

Comment: me esta pasando lo mismo si ya lo pudiste solucionar por favor dime como